# Outlook 2013 gives Windows Security warning when adding live account

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

I have been trying to add my live.com account to Outlook 2013 but keep getting the below error.

[image]

I have tried creating a new profile and other things listed at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/829918. I have also tried clearing Vault in Control Panel and other things as listed at [Outlook login/windows security pops up every time](https://superuser.com/questions/254518/outlook-login-windows-security-pops-up-every-time).

Any other thing left? Anyone knows how to solve this problem?

Comment: You are supposed to enter your password there

Comment: @kinokijuf Yes, I did enter my password. The message occurs again even after that. I have actually tried finding the solution on a lot of websites for the problem.

Comment: Hm, do you have 2-factor authentication enabled on your live account?

Comment: @allquixotic Yes. I have that enabled.

Comment: It's probably asking you again and again because your Microsoft account password is a combination of your regular password, **AND** an OTP from your 2-factor device. You should see about obtaining a one-time password from Microsoft like you get for a Google account.

Comment: @allquixotic Understood the reasoning but wasn't able to understand the solution. Does Microsoft provide one-time password for outlook 2013 in such cases? For normal login on outlook.com it does but for outlook 2013?

Comment: @AseemBansal - Microsoft has a process to generate application passwords just like Google does considering they use the exact same standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on this post on [WinSupersite](http://winsupersite.com/cloud/enable-and-use-two-step-authentication-your-microsoft-account) and the comments to this question, it looks like you need to generate an **App Password** for Outlook 2013, since you have two-factor auth enabled.

> You can generate an app password at the [Microsoft account management web site](https://account.live.com/), again from the [Security info view](https://account.live.com/proofs/Manage). Just tap the link Create a new app password under App Passwords. When you do, you’ll be provided with an app password that you can type (or copy and paste) into the application.

This step is only necessary because Outlook 2013 does not natively support the two-factor authentication mechanism where it would ask you first for your password and then for your One-Time Password (OTP) generated by your second factor. The next release of Outlook might, but who knows; Microsoft hasn't announced the feature set yet.

The app password is an un-changing password that basically bypasses the two-factor authentication system, without making you use your *actual* password. An app password can still be used as a substitute for your two-factor login (effectively making your login one-factor for the purposes of this password), so be careful that you do not leak your app password to any public location.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This worked when nothing else was working.

Comment: It's interesting how 2-step authentication works on signing to Office in general, but not for Outlook specifically...

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi - Its not really all that interesting.  Office 2013 has OneDrive intergration.   Outlook is primarly an MS-Exchange email client before anything else.  Office 2013 is also more-or-less a 2012 product.  This means the 2-factor authentication support added to these email services in the last two years can't be supported.  Of course thats the reason the application password exists anyways.